# Merging multiple pieces of state into component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a question regarding how one should handle state between multiple components. Let's say I have the following components structure:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component<...> {
    public render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
            <SomeComponent {...this.props} />
            <SomeOtherComponent = {...this.props} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

The connect method looks like this

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.ExampleComponent, 
    ExampleComponentStore.actionCreators                 
)(ExampleComponent) as typeof ExampleComponent;
```

I have of course simplified the examples above to illustrate what I'm asking for.

Here the underlying components SomeComponent and SomeOtherComponent uses the parents state for updating. I don't know if this is the right approach, what I would have ideally is that each component has it's own piece of state, and that the top level component has access to all underlying components state. Something like this at the top level

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => Object.assign(state.ExampleComponent, state.SomeComponent, state.SomeOtherComponent), 
    ExampleComponentStore.actionCreators                 
)(ExampleComponent) as typeof ExampleComponent;
```

However this  does not work when the state is updating. Is the right approach here to have a top level component that have all the state for the other components, and pass them as props? Or should all child components have their own state that is merged at the top level component as needed? I appreciate any input.

Comment: As a side note, your second `mapState` definition is very broken - it will mutate `state.ExampleComponent`.  You should instead return a new object that includes the pieces of data you want as props for the component.  Also, I personally recommend writing the `mapState` function separately for readability, instead of trying to write it inline inside of the `connect` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be one of those "generally speaking answers" as there are no hard and fast rules when it come to which component(s) should have be `connect`ed and which should be passed as props, but here are my thoughts on it.

```
<SomeComponent {...this.props} />
<SomeOtherComponent = {...this.props} />
```

I do not recommend passing all of the `props` from one component to it's children.  The main reason for this is it makes it very difficult to determine if the [component should update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and you'll probably end up with a lof of unnecessary renders when unrelated `props` change.  You are better off passing just the `props` that are required.  It's a little more effort in maintenance, but it's worth it in the long run.

If `SomeComponent` and `SomeOtherComponent` have their own state in the redux store, there isn't much harm in `connect`ing them to the store as well to get their state.  In fact, react-redux does a great job of determining if the component should update based on it's state and props, so in many cases you get a performance improvement from this.  **This is my recommendation to you**.

If they still need some values from the parent component's state, they can either map those themselves, or have them passed from the parent.  `connect`ed components can still accept `props` like standard components.

---

@markerikson mentioned this in the comments, but I'll include it here too:

```
(state: ApplicationState) => Object.assign(state.ExampleComponent, state.SomeComponent, state.SomeOtherComponent)
```

This `mapStateToProps` is broken.  the first parameter of `Object.assign` is the one that get mutated.  This is more correctly written as

```
(state: ApplicationState) => Object.assign({}, state.ExampleComponent, state.SomeComponent, state.SomeOtherComponent)
```

Or using  [object spread](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#spread)

```
(state: ApplicationState) => ({ ...state.ExampleComponent, ...state.SomeComponent, ...state.SomeOtherComponent })
```

Bearing in mind that this will flatten the state so if there are any duplicate keys between each branch of the state tree, some of them will be lost.  You may be better off passing in the whole state tree as is if this is what you want to do.

---

> what I would have ideally is that each component has it's own piece of state, and that the top level component has access to all underlying components state.

I'm curious why the top level component needs access to the underlying component's state.

Don't get me wrong, in redux, it's often normal for components to use the same pieces of state as one another (encouraged in some cases), but in this case, I don't see why it needs it itself, other than passing it on the the underlying components (if that's the approach you take).

Comment: Thanks for a really good and outfilling answer. The top level component might in some cases need the state to find out what it should / shouldn't display, and I was just wondering what different approaches one might use to achieve that.

Comment: As I said, there are often cases to include the same state into multiple components, so it may be valid for you (sounds like it is).  It is also valid for a component to return `null` if it doesn't want to render anything, so often the conditional logic can be pushed down to the component with the state.  Remember, there are no hard and fast rules here, find the pattern that works best for you and run with it.